# Cannot find module '@angular/material-moment-adapter'

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-material2

Why is this not working? I try importing the MomentDateAdapter as shown on the [angular website](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) but Visual Studio Code keeps complaining it cant find @angular/material-moment-adapter. What am I doing wrong?

> version info:  Angular CLI: 1.5.0 Node: 6.11.0 OS: darwin x64 Angular:
>   4.4.6 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ... http, language-service, platform-browser ... platform-browser-dynamic,
>   router, tsc-wrapped
>
> @angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12 @angular/cli: 1.5.0 @angular/material:
>   2.0.0-beta.12 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.32 @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20 @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35
>   @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0 @ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
>   @schematics/angular: 0.1.1 typescript: 2.3.4 webpack: 3.8.1

Comment: Do you have '@angular/material-moment-adapter' in node_modules?

Comment: Seems like you need to `import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter'` and import `MatMomentDateModule` in app.module.ts. hope this will fix it

Comment: I do not have @angular/material-moment-adapter in my node_modules. I have @angular/language-service, @angular/material, @angular/platform-browser. No @angular/material-moment-adapter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `@angular/material-moment-adapter` requires Angular v5 and up and was only introduced [recently (in `5.0.0-rc0`)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5.0.0-rc0), you have to update your dependencies as follows:

```bash
npm install -s @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}@'^5.0.1' rxjs@'^5.5.2'
npm install -E typescript@2.4.2
```

Adapted from https://update.angular.io

**EDIT**:

Note: As of NPMJS 5, you no longer have to specify the `--save` flag as this is the default option (see [this blog post on changes to NPMJS 5](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500) for more info (under the *breaking changes* section)):

```bash
npm i @angular/{animations,common,compiler,core,forms,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,router}@latest rxjs@latest moment
npm i -D typescript@2.9
```

(P.S. The `-D` flag is an alias of `--save-dev`)

Comment: ran the first command got back a bunch of lines like this: "@angular/animations@5.1.1 invalid" and "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@5.1.1 invalid"

Comment: I was having issues running those commands but based on what you said about angular 5 being required I used the now updated CLI to generate a new project and copied the package.json file from the fresh project over and that seemed to work.

Comment: Down voter, could you explain why you downvoted this answer?

Comment: @Edric: I think it would be nice to extend your answer (because this one is the accepted) with the importance of adding moment.js as [xudre wrote it below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816319/cannot-find-module-angular-material-moment-adapter#answer-50711379)

Comment: @Burnee Thanks for the heads up! I've added what you've said in my answer.

Comment: Yeah this is not enough.

Comment: @Mulperi Could you clarify?

Answer (score 71):

For those, like me, that also reached this question and already have the lastest **@angular 5+**.

Don't forget to install [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com): `npm i moment` *(as I did )*

Comment: Running this plus `npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter` worked for me.

Answer (score 49):

Just run this command using npm for installing *@angular/material-moment-adapter*:

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

Answer (score 12):

Just run this CMD

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

If it shows any error install

```
npm i moment
```

Answer (score 10):

Check out this: https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxamabemnyx

Something to note you will have to manually install the module: npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter

Looking at the package.json it's missing.

Comment: @Curtis See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

run the command ctrl + c for terminate. Then run again ng serve to **re-run the application**. after that, you can see the following image. [image]

The issue is here. The moment js

Then run the command to install moment.js by running following common in application location.

```
npm i moment
```

After that, you can see it's installed as in the following image.

[image]
In my case, the issue was correct by these steps.

Answer (score 1):

You must intall in @angular 5+

1. moment.js
   `npm i moment`

2.Material Moment Adapter
`npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter`

[Here is the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material-moment-adapter) You can visit here.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the following command on Angular CLI

```
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest step I can think of would be go to your npm package, `right click` and `delete`, and run command in git bash in project folder - `npm install`. Installation will proceed. Other option is `cd` into your `c` drive, and run `npm list -g` which will list all the modules you got in global setting, you would try to find the one that you are missing in this question. Third option, if nothing works blow away your global node module and re-install it. Instruction on how to do so is already answered in this link below.
[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)
`Dominic Tancredi` has answered it so well. he has mentioned about how to do so in `Mac`, you would remove `sudo`from commands that he has mentioned to make it work in `Windows`.